# custom slider in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, slider

In bottom lines I describe that how these sliders operate:
When the pins of slider move to top, for minimum pin , the color of whole of the place under this pin becomes red for colored slider and white for black&white slider and for maximum pin , when this pin move to bottom, color of whole of the place top of this pin becomes blue for colored slider and black for black&white slider
How I can change color before thumb of slider? (means this part of the text: for minimum pin , the color of whole of the place under this pin becomes red for colored slider and white for black&white slider)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is called Range selector. There are sample projects [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28717/A-custom-range-selector-control-in-C-with-a-little), [Here](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/RangeSliderWPF/), and [Here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/09/06/wpf-range-slider-control/)